How can I have annotation bboxes above all lines when using multiple axes?
Given the following code:
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timestamp
from numpy import arange

data = DataFrame({'A': arange(100, 200), 'B': arange(500, 400, -1)}, index=date_range('2024-01-01', periods=100))
ax_a = data['A'].plot(color='C0')
ax_b = data['B'].plot(color='C1', secondary_y=True)
ax_a.annotate(
    '', (Timestamp('2024-01-15'), 120), xytext=(Timestamp('2024-03-20'), 120),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='C0', ),
)
ax_a.annotate(f'Label A', (Timestamp('2024-03-02'), 120), bbox=dict(fc="0.8"))
ax_b.annotate(
    '', (Timestamp('2024-03-20'), 420), xytext=(Timestamp('2024-01-15'), 420),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='C1', ),
)
ax_b.annotate(f'Label B', (Timestamp('2024-02-02'), 420), bbox=dict(fc="0.8"))

I get the following plot:

What should I change such that none of the lines, including the annotation arrows, overlap either of the annotation bboxes and their content?
As you can see above, currently any lines plotted on ax_b overlap the bbox for "Label A".

I think you can't do this, because first ax_a is drawn with all its artits and only then ax_b is drawn (given they have the same zorder), again with all its artists. This means that zorder is only significant within an axes, not across different axes objects. Therefore you can't interleave the drawing orders of artists from one Axes with those from another..
The only workaround I can offer is to draw the label A also on ax_b, i.e. using
ax_b.annotate(f'Label A', (Timestamp('2024-03-02'), 120), bbox=dict(fc="0.8"), xycoords=ax_a.transData)



I don't see your answer as a workaround, looks totally reasonable, thanks!
